# How to change only one property and leave others in the same value?

Tags: html, css

Here is the footer:

```css
.smartFooter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  color: white;
}
.footerContainer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}
.footerLogo {
  margin-top: 20%;
}
.footerAbout {
  display: table-cell;
}
.footerProducts {
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<footer class="smartFooter">
  <div class="footerContainer">

    <div class="footerLogo">
      <img src="img/smart_logo.png" alt="logo" width="200">
    </div>

    <div class="footerAbout">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Like us on Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Add us on Google Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Dribbble</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Pinterest</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footerProducts">
      <h3>Products</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Like us on Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Add us on Google Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Dribbble</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Pinterest</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

But when I try to change a property of class="footerLogo" every sell takes the same value. For example - if I try to write for class="footerLogo" value "margin-top" then all the footer content begins to change.

How can I change the value ONLY of a red lined classes?
[image]

Comment: Because your container is displaying as `table`, which makes the inner elements cells inside the table. If one cell has a higher margin, all the cells will have a higher margin. There are very little reasons why you'd need to use `display:table` these days, what is the look you're looking for exactly?

Comment: @dayuloli, have you any idea how to make the same effect (full width and centered positon) but without this mistake?

Comment: Try to add an image of what you're attempting to accomplish. Anything that better describes it. Not sure what you're shooting for 100%.

Comment: @GHKarim, I added the image - I need something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without something more solid, can't help you much there.

```css
.smartFooter {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  color: white;
}

.footerLogo, .footerAbout, .footerProducts {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

.footerLogo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="smartFooter">
    <div class="footerLogo">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="logo">
    </div>

    <div class="footerAbout">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Like us on Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Add us on Google Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Dribbble</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Pinterest</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footerProducts">
      <h3>Products</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Like us on Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Add us on Google Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Dribbble</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i></i>Follow us on Pinterest</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div
</footer>
```

Note the image is only 100px high/wide. If the margin is too high then they'd all have a weird space at the top anyways.

It's also usually not what you meant by `margin-top:20px` The 20% is relation to the width, not the viewport height. It's best to use `px` values instead of `%`.

Comment: it gives another effect - if I use more divs then they move to the second row :(

Comment: You'll need to provide a better description of what you're looking for in your question. Possibly producing a jsFiddle so we know where you're at. If you have a footer where you don't know the number of columns it'll have, then maybe try flexbox. Look at the `footer` element on this [site](http://asialinks.org/en/home/), for example.

Comment: Sorry, I used your variant not properly. Now everything works, thank you.